# CSS-how to text-indent a nested unordered list

Tags: html, css

[image: This is where I am at]

I do not know if this is possible, but I'm trying to indent the <li> in red to wrap underneath itself with CSS. I've used text-indent, padding, margin, and cannot get it to work. The <li> in red seems to be set at the same x/y coordinate as the green text. It only lets me push it away from the time (in green).

I can use a table, but I'm trying to accomplish this with CSS.

The image above is where I am at. The image below is what I am after.

[image: This is what I'm after]

**HTML**

```
<div class="agendaList">
    <ul>
        <li>Day, Month Date</li>
            <ul>
                <li>0:00 am</li>
                <li>This is where the event description will appear. I would like for it to wrap under itself and not under the time. How do I start the wrap at the first word in the first sentence (This) of this &lt;li&gt;.</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Day, Month Date</li>
            <ul>
                <li>0:00 am</li>
                <li>This is where the event description will appear. I would like for it to wrap under itself and not under the time. How do I start the wrap at the first word in the first sentence (This) of this &lt;li&gt;.</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.agendaList ul ul {
    list-style: disc;
    /* list-style-image: url(bullet.gif); */
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.agendaList ul ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    color: green;
}

.agendaList ul ul li:last-child {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

Comment: A table would work perfectly

Comment: Without changing any markup, you could do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/8BgsC/).

Comment: @ZachSaucier, you are right, but I would like to know if there is a way of doing this or not. Thanks.

Comment: You probably should change the ending style tag to style instead of script.

Comment: @milkIt Just about anything is possible, it's up to us to decide what is best and whether a decision is worth it

Comment: @DeadlyChambers, yeah I noticed that too. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, that is exactly what I was looking for. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: On a side note your HTML is invalid, `li` is the only valid child of `ul` your nested `ul` should be inside an `li`. Further more you only need one outer list.

Comment: @JonP, thanks, it is invalid html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options:

Absolutely position the first `li` element and then use a margin to add space to the second list item.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bYV52/)

```
.agendaList ul ul li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
}
.agendaList ul ul li:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 65px;
}
```

Alternatively, a better option would be to set the display of both `li` elements to `table-cell`. Add `white-space:nowrap` to the first `li` in order to prevent the text from wrapping.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/88Z8E/)

```
.agendaList ul ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    list-style:none;
    color:green;
}
.agendaList ul ul li:first-child {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.agendaList ul ul li:last-child {
    color: red;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I'm definitely going to go over this some more to get a better understanding.

Comment: I prefer the first example for visual aesthetics. In the first example, the time does not effect the copy on the right of it, and keeps the copy left aligned with adequate margin spacing. For the second example, the time effects the copy on the right and creates extra character spaces which destroys the left alignment of the copy. By time effecting the copy, I mean, 9:00am is shorter and 12:00pm is longer in width which effects the copy on the right. Again, thank you.